# How do I console log the text inside of html element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I want to console log the text "Jingle All the Way [Family Fun Edition] [DVD] [1996]" on https://www.bestbuy.com/site/jingle-all-the-way-family-fun-edition-dvd-1996/8538512.p?skuId=8538512.
I am using axios , cheerio.

```
(async () =>{
   const { data } = await axios.get(productUrl);
   const $ = cheerio.load(data)
   const title = $('h1')[0];
   console.log(title)
   
})();
```

If you can help me please let me know. This should be very simple but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(async () =>{
   const { data } = await axios.get(productUrl);
   const $ = cheerio.load(data)
   const title = $('h1');
   console.log(title.text());
   
})();
```

Comment: It gives me that text is not a function. That is what I initially though would work before I made the post but I keep getting that error.

Comment: Are you getting any data from 'cheerio.load(data)'? try 'const $ = await cheerio.load(data)' and then try to do '$('h1')[0].text();'

Comment: Yes, when I console.log(data) I get all the html .

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I edited my answer, check again 'console.log(title.text());'

Comment: It works now . If you can explain what you did and what my initial problem was I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I have looked in http://zetcode.com/javascript/cheerio/ - See the section 'Cheerio title'. Please mark upvote and accept answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line 3 to `const $ = await cheerio.load(data)`